# Visual Studio C++ structure on Github

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github

Currently, my project structure of VS have filtered structure.
But my Github just have a single folder with all .cpp and .h inside it. How do I maintain the structure?

Comment: _"How do I maintain the structure?"_ - Create folder. Move file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS doesn't create directories for you.  The view you see is "filters".  Organization on the disk is flat unless you tell it otherwise, and it's moderately painful.  The project on github will reflect the directory structure, not VS's "filters".

Comment: So this is VS and nothing related to C++?